# Are default arguments of object type constructed every time they aren't specified?

Tags: c++

I've seen some code where there is a method with some default arguments which are of object type and it got me wondering what happens when the default arguments aren't specified by a caller. In "The C++ Programming Language" Stroustrup says this:

> A default argument is type checked at the time of the function declaration and evaluated at the time of the call.

For example, if there is a method declared like this will it a new string be constructed every time this method is called without passing in `default_string`?:

```
void foo(int param, std::string default_string = {});
```

The reason I was wondering about this was if I were to implement such a method where callers more often than not don't provide the default arguments would it be better to not use default arguments at all and define two methods with and without these arguments to avoid costly construction of unused arguments?

Comment: That really depends on how the argument is used in the function. If it is necessary then you'll have to construct it sooner or later. Chances are constructing an empty string isn't as expensive as you might think, and if this isn't a hotspot in your program you won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Most of the time, avoiding code duplication is preferable to premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Object {
  Object(bool expensive = true) {
    if (expensive) {
      std::cout << "Oh, I am so expensive!" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Ah, this was cheap." << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

void foo(Object o = {}) {}

int main() {
  foo(Object(true));
  foo(Object(false));
  foo();
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

```
[:~/tmp] $ g++ -std=c++2a constr2.cpp && ./a.out
Oh, I am so expensive!
Ah, this was cheap.
Oh, I am so expensive!
Oh, I am so expensive!
```

Note that the compiler cannot omit the construction of `Object` if it cannot prove that it has no side-effects. In the example, even if it realizes that `o` will not be used in the body of `foo`, it cannot leave out the print.